# Custom routing for plugins

Tags: plugins, api, routing

I am making a plugin that needs a page that  can be accessed from the outside, pretty much like an API, and have the url like so,

http://xxxxx/custom_method?parameter=xxxxx&something=xxxx

is there a clean way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordPress Way of doing it is using `query_vars` so first you add you vars to the array:

```
//add to query vars
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $new_vars = array('custom_method','cm_parameter');
    $vars = $new_vars + $vars;
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

then you can check in your plugin for the vars:

```
global $wp; 
    if (array_key_exists('custom_method', $wp->query_vars) && isset($wp->query_vars['custom_method'])){
      //do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: why both array_key_exists and isset ? :)

Comment: first we make sure its a valid acceptable query_var, and then if it has a value to avoid warnings and notices.

Comment: Both effectively do the same thing though don't they? .. neither checks if the value is an empty string, they just check the key is set... am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks, this did it. At first I did not understand the mechanism of query_var and was confused but after looking at the Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries and print_ring the $wp->query_var, I now have a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: You should read [this answer on the difference between `isset` and `array_key_exists`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3210982/519702). You *never* need to use both.

Comment: `isset` is the better choice, kill two birds with one function, it returns `FALSE` when not set, where as `array_key_exists` returns `TRUE` just by the mere presence of a `[key]` regardless if it has a `value` or not.